# Serial monitor doesn't work with piezo buzzer

Tags: serial, led, nodemcu, piezo, proximity

So I can't see the distance of the proximity sensor anymore as soon as I type the code for the piezo buzzer. I've tried many things but it doesn't work.. Can anybody help me fixing this?

```
int trigPin = D7;
int echoPin = D8;
int BLUE = D3; //D3 zit in blauw
int GREEN = D4;
int RED = D5;
int piezoPin = D10;

void setup() {// deze code gaat maar 1 keer
  Serial.begin (115200);
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);

  pinMode(GREEN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(BLUE, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RED, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() { //code wordt steeds herhaalt
  long duration, distance;
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);  
  delayMicroseconds(2); 
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH); // trig zendt een signaal uit
  delayMicroseconds(10); 
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH); // kijkt hoelang het duurt totdat signaal heen en weer gaat
  distance = (duration/2) / 29.1; 
  // omdat het signaal heen wordt gezonden moet het door twee gedeelt worden
  // snelheid van geluid door lucht is circa 29 microseconden per cm dus gedeelt 29.

    Serial.print(distance);
    Serial.println(" cm");

//afstand wordt in cm weergegeven in serial monitor

  delay(500);

   if ((distance > 100) && (distance <= 150)){ //dit gebeurd er als de afstand vanaf sensor tussen groter dan 100 cm en gelijk aan of kleiner dan 150 cm is.
    analogWrite(BLUE, 0);
    analogWrite(GREEN, 255);
    analogWrite(RED, 0);

    tone(piezoPin, 1000, 1000); // toon duurt 1 seconden
    delay(2000); // 2 seconden geen geluid
    tone(piezoPin, 1000, 1000);
    delay(2000);

   }

   else if ((distance > 50) && (distance <= 100)){ //dit gebeurd er als de afstand vanaf sensor tussen groter dan 50 cm en gelijk aan of kleiner dan 100 cm is.
    Serial.println("Ga weg!");

    analogWrite(BLUE, 0);
    analogWrite(GREEN, 102);
    analogWrite(RED, 252);

    tone(piezoPin, 1000, 700); // toon duurt 0.7 seconden
    delay(1000); // 1 seconde geen geluid
    tone(piezoPin, 1000, 700);
    delay(1000);

  }

  else if ((distance >= 0) && (distance <= 50)){ //dit gebeurd er als de afstand vanaf sensor tussen groter dan of gelijk aan 0 cm en gelijk aan of kleiner dan 50 cm is.

    analogWrite(BLUE, 0);
    analogWrite(GREEN, 0);
    analogWrite(RED, 255);

    tone(piezoPin, 1000, 200); // toon duurt 0,2 seconden
    delay(100); // 0,1 seconden geen geluid
    tone(piezoPin, 1000, 200);
    delay(100);

  }

   else {
    analogWrite(BLUE, 0);
    analogWrite(GREEN, 0);
    analogWrite(RED, 0);

 }

}
```

Comment: I use a the NodeMCU

Comment: but there is no pin labeled D10 on NodeMCU

Comment: Can you explain what you have tried?

Comment: I have deleted some code and checked if anything was broken with my friend's code and redownloaded arduino

Answer (score 2):

Pin D10 of NodeMcu is io 1 which is RX pin of Serial interface of the esp8266. Serial is on NodeMCU connected to USB. The pin is on board labeled RX.

D8 is boot config pin io 15. It must have pulldown on board. The pulldown can disturb the input on this pin. Use D6 (io 12) as echoPin.

Comment: I have changed the pin and it kind of works but not really good because it doesn't give the right distance it goes from 160 cm to 0 cm without moving anything...

Comment: but that is a different problem

Comment: D8 is io 15. it has a pulldown circuit on board. I don't know if it can disturb the measurement

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what io means. This is my first time programming with this program

Comment: try D6 (io 12) instead of D8

Comment: @TeddySmit, accept the answer to mark the question solved